# ¿Cómo obtener la moda de un dataframe con pandas en Python?

Tags: python, array, pandas, dataframe, estadística

Tengo un dataframe con varia columnas con números. Columnas con labels UNO, DOS... CINCO.
Y quiero hallar la moda.

Lo he hecho uniendo en una SERIES todas las columnas buscando la MODA.

Pero no me gusta, seguro que hay una manera más elegante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué hago mal?

Gracias

Comment: Hola. De la pregunta no me queda muy claro si la moda la necesita por fila, columna o de todo el dataframe. ¿Cuál de las 3 modas necesita?

Comment: En este caso, de todos las columnas de todo el dataframe.  Lo he realizado pero como ves quizás un poco a lo bestia.

Comment: Ok, preguntaba porque hay de varias formas: df.mode tiene un argumento para hacerlo por columnas o listas por ejemplo: df.mode(axis=0) donde 0 es por fila, y 1 por columna. O si quieres de TODOS los datos, también podrías hacer algo así df.values.tolist().mode()

Comment: Con axis he hecho pruebas, y tampoco me iba.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(df[["uno", "dos", "tres"]].values.flatten()).mode()[0]
```

Con `df.values` obtenemos un `array` de las dimensiones originales y con [`flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten) lo  "aplanamos" a uno de una sola dimensión. Lo único que restaría es usar `pd.Series()` para transformarlo en una `Serie` y poder usar `mode()`

Comment: Gracias. Imagina que además de las columnas que te he puesto hay más ( mi caso),  como fechas, objetos, string... y tu solo necesitas hacer la MODA de todos los números de las columnas UNO a CINCO. ese flatten() no es de todo el array. ¿Se puede?, ¿Cómo?

Comment: Si sabes el número de columnas, se puede hacer algo así: pd.Series(df.iloc[:,1:4].values.flatten()).mode()[0]

Comment: Selecciona las columnas del dataframe antes de `values`, fijate mi edición

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma, obteniendo primero la frecuencia absoluta, se transforma de tipo pandas a numpy y con max() se obtiene el numero mayor

```
moda = pd.crosstab(index=matriz, columns="count").to_numpy().max()   
# .crosstab genera la agrupacion o la frecuencia absoluta
# .to_numpy() convierte el DataFrame a arreglo numpy
# max() obtiene el maximo valor

print("moda = ", moda)
```